# Require specific string as optional key in TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript, object, types

I have a situation where I could have a number of optional, t-shirt size props added to an object. Is there a way to define a type and set it as the optional key's type in an interface?

```
type Size = `xxs` | `xs` | `s` | `m` | `l` | `xl` | `xxl`;

interface Sizes {
  [key: Size]: string;
   ^^^
}
```

The above example presents me with the following error:

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.ts(1337)

I then found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438012/an-index-signature-parameter-type-cannot-be-a-union-type-consider-using-a-mappe), and modified my code as follows:

```
type Size = `xxs` | `xs` | `s` | `m` | `l` | `xl` | `xxl`;

interface Sizes {
  [key in Size]: string;
   ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

But am then presented with the following errors:

> A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1169)

> A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts(2464)

> Cannot find name 'key'.ts(2304)

I've obviously missed something fairly crucial in my implementation. Any explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) is not an interface.  You can make it a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) instead of an interface:

```
type TSizes = { [K in Size]?: string };
```

Note that I put the `?` in there which makes the properties optional, as you presumably want.

Once you have such a named type you can make an interface that extends it (since all of its property names are statically known):

```
interface ISizes extends TSizes { }
```

Or you can use the built-in [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) and [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) utility types to do both at the same time:

```
interface Sizes extends Partial<Record<Size, string>> { }
```

Then, `Sizes` is an interface with optional property keys from `Size` whose values are of type `string`:

```
const s: Sizes = {
    s: "foo",
    m: "bar",
    xxl: "bazzz"
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgL2gXigAwB4YM5qgH3Rz0LVwPQFsT0AbGzeizDegbgFgAob0SKACrwk2KKgDeUANoBpKHAB2sRBAC6AfgBcUbMABOigOZQAvpx5dFwCHoBmAQwDG0AJLCIoiBmsKAJqKEVUUkTbm4rGwdnZREoLx9-KAAFez1gOHtaAB4AJQhHAHs9Xyz3ABodfSMAPmqoEKgwrkKFXR1td1EJbihe9qgAIlsCgoGynr7KbQGAI1Sxid6sWmm5hHWB7lCuIA)

Comment: Thanks for this. I think its high time I bury myself in the documentation.