# Bypassing TS1337 for custom form validators in angular TS version 3.8

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing my own custom form validators for angular with the following template.

```js
static customFunction(param: number, param2: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    return { customError: {param, param2} };
  };
}
```

Instead of `key:string` I want to only allow a range of items from a defined enum.

```js
export enum FormErrorEnum {
  unknown = 'unknown',
  customError = 'customError',
}

export type FormError = keyof typeof FormErrorEnum;
```

If I try to use either `[key: FormError]: any` or `[key in FormError]:any` I will get one of two errors.

`[key: FormError]: any` results in a TS1337.
`[key in FormError]:any` results in the return (`customError: {param,param2}` being refused as it does not include all entires in the enum.

---

I have already looked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438012/an-index-signature-parameter-type-cannot-be-a-union-type-consider-using-a-mappe) thread. TS version is 3.8 - upgrading is an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use literal types instead of enums.

```js
export type FormError  = 'unknown' | 'customError';

const error1: FormError = 'unknown'; // ok
const error2: FormError = 'illegal'; // error
```

The return type in your customFunction should be:

```js
type ErrorResult = {
    [P in FormError]?: any;
};
```

If you allow exactly one property of FormError:

```js
type ErrorResult = {
    [P in FormError]: { [K in P]: any };
}[FormError];
```

The idea behind this is: Create the required type for each key: `{ [K in P]: any }`. Put them in a map: `{ [P in FormError]: {...} }`. Get the values of the map: `[FormError]`

Comment: Sorry but this does not work. This gives me the same errors as listed above. Can you show me an example using the `customFunction` where it returns an object using one of these types?

Comment: Do you want to allow multiple keys ({ unknown: {...}, customError: {...}} and no keys ({})? Or exactly one key is the preferred?

Comment: Allow multiple but it should not be required.

Comment: Out of interest if I only wanted 1 of the items what would that look like?

Comment: Any way to extend the `ErrorResult` type created in last code block?