# Why the genetric type can not be used as type for keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
type Test<T extends string, V extends unknown> = {
  [Key: T]: V;
}

type Test<T extends string, V extends unknown> = {
  [Key in T]: V;
}
```

From the code above, T extends string,why T can not be used as Key's type and it output an error `An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.` But if replace `Key: T` with `Key in T`, it works.

Comment: try doing the property optional, it may help, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64694571/17239546

Comment: The top one is an index signature and the bottom one is a mapped type; they look similar but are distinct.  See the answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for in TypeScript is called Utility Type - Record

For example:

```ts
type Test<T extends string, V extends unknown> = Record<T, V>;
```

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type