# How can I restrict fields in an interface to match the fields of a generic parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics, index-signature

I would like to define an interface (or other type?) that describes another object (whose type should be provided as a generic parameter).

Basically, it should look something like this:

```
interface IDescriptor<T extends object> {
    propSet1?: (keyof T)[];
    
    propSet2?: (keyof T)[];
}
```

So far, so good - now I can only list properties that are actually found in whichever type is provided for type parameter `T` in `propSet1` and `propSet2`.

---

As a simple example, imagine a type `Person`:

```
class Person {
    firstName?: string;
    
    lastName?: string;
    
    age?: number;
}
```

Now, in type `IDescriptor<Person>`, `propSet1` and `propSet2` can only contain either of the values `'firstName'`, `'lastName'`, and `'age'`.

---

**However, I now require `IDescriptor` to optionally contain some additional information on each of the fields from `T`.**
Concretely, I would like to specify the following object literal:

```
let desc: IDescriptor<Person> = {
    propSet1: ['firstName', 'lastName'],
    propSet2: ['lastName', 'age'],
    propInfo: {
        lastName: {
            suggestionList: 'surnames'
        },
        age: {
            maxValue: 120
        }
    }
};
```

In the above example, the possible options are defined in the following interface:

```
interface IPropOptions {
    suggestionList?: string;
    maxValue?: number;
}
```

Now, how do I declare the `propInfo` property?

The two approaches I have thought of fail for different reasons:

I have tried uing the `in` operator:

```
propInfo?: {
    [key in T]: IPropOptions;
};
```

This fails with the message

> TS2322: Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
>   Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.

I have tried using a `keyof` expression:

```
propInfo?: {
    [key: keyof T]: IPropOptions;
};
```

Unfortunately, this fails with the message

> TS1337: An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

Then, I have also tried using a map, as suggested:

```
propInfo?: Map<keyof T, IPropOptions>
```

This in itself appears to be valid, but here, I don't know how to specify the value as an object literal.

**Is there any way to solve this as desired? I am especially unsure as there appear to be subtle differences in what is or is not allowed depending on e.g. whether I declare something as an interface or as a "type".**

Comment: "Assuming that the possible options like `suggestionList` and `maxValue` are defined in an interface `IPropOptions`" Instead of assuming could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates what you're talking about when we paste it into our own IDEs?  Otherwise I have to try to define things myself and then hoping I've done it right

Comment: Also are you just looking for `{[K in keyof T]: IPropOptions}` which is a *mapped object type* (which has nothing whatsoever to do with `Map`)?  This feels like a typo to me, if so

Comment: @jcalz: Done. The explicit interface declaration is added.

Comment: @jcalz: Actually, that might be the solution. Among variou resources, I was looking at [that other quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438012) and maybe got confused about using `in` directly with a type rather than `keyof <type>`.

Comment: So then I guess either this should be closed as "caused by a typo" or answered with "use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) as suggested"?

Comment: @jcalz: Thank you, as none of these options really describe the crux of the problem I had, I have taken the liberty to [post my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75805593/5206621). I will keep it unaccepted for a little while, though, in case you or someone else writes a more comprehensive answer on the concept.

Answer (score 0):

The comments by user [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) helped me to find the answer:

In TypeScript, a "mapped object type" is actually a set term denoting a [specific language concept](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), not just a generic way to refer to the standard map types, as I had mistakenly thought.

Thus, the error message

> Consider using a mapped object type instead.

was actually pointing out the right syntax to use for the concept that I thought I was already using:

```
propInfo?: {
    [key in keyof T]: IPropOptions;
};
```

appears to do what I am looking for.